# Export all contacts having Numeric last name?

Tags: soql, query, number

I have a issue where in our Org, last name of many contacts has been changed to Numeric.

I need to take an extract of all those contacts having number in their last name along with their ID.

I tried searching through the forum and tried multiple queries including isNumeric(Column) etc but it is not working.

Comment: can you add more details on how you are trying to achieve this? code, if any ?

Comment: as i wrote, i tried with IsNumeric(LastName) in query which gave aggregate error. Also tried with strings but it did not parse.

Answer (score 3):

The SOQL for this is a bit convoluted, so I'd recommend using a formula, then you can easily make a query for it.

The formula is a checkbox return type:

```
ISNUMBER(LastName)
```

And the query simply becomes:

```
SELECT Id, LastName FROM Contact WHERE Last_Name_Is_Numeric__c = TRUE
```

Without a formula, you end up having to write something like this:

```
SELECT Id, LastName FROM Contact
WHERE LastName LIKE '%0%' OR
      LastName LIKE '%1%' OR
      LastName LIKE '%2%' OR
      LastName LIKE '%3%' OR
      LastName LIKE '%4%' OR
      LastName LIKE '%5%' OR
      LastName LIKE '%6%' OR
      LastName LIKE '%7%' OR
      LastName LIKE '%8%' OR
      LastName LIKE '%9%'
```

Comment: Age old strategy for augmenting SOQL.

Comment: Also if the numeric last names all start with a number, you could use something like `WHERE LastName >= '0' OR LastName <= '999999999'`.